# What are the locations of the gnomes?

Tags: stranger-things-the-game

I can't find the second and fifth gnome locations Any suggestions? I've tried everything but I can't find them.

Answer (score 1):

2nd gnome is in the tree maze down near the lab (bottom right of map) - you need Will to crawl through a pipe

Comment: I'd say the forest maze is more accessible from the far right of the map instead of the bottom right. Bottom right is where the cave maze is.

Answer (score 0):

5th gnome is in the middle school